# What is the best way to do automated UI testing on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, functional-testing

What is the best way to do automated UI testing on the iPhone?

__*_* is to iPhone as Selenium is to web apps

Comment: In the future I would phrase your question titles differently. Remember that this is a QA site and people search on titles... As helpful as the answer to this may be, it's diminished if people can't find it.

Comment: Your question is quite vague, Please be more specif on what you're testing, is it native apps? or Mobile Web?

Comment: This was closed due to the specific wording (which I think is fine, myself), but I believe it duplicates what was asked here: [Is there a good tutorial on cocoa touch automated UI testing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393190/is-there-a-good-tutorial-on-cocoa-touch-automated-ui-testing), where you might find some resources that answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

There's in-built SDK support for automated UI testing via `UIAutomation`:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/Introduction/Introduction.html

Write your tests in JavaScript, and execute them via instruments. The link above should get you started.