# Best Resources for UIAutomation Testing for iOS Applications

Tags: iphone, ios, automated-tests, instruments, ios-ui-automation

Testing with UIAutomation on Instruments is great, however, the documentation and resources around it are either non-existent or in hiding.  What are the best resources (documentation, blog posts, Stack Overflow questions) that have helped you in implementing this on your projects?  Are there any good open source testing scripts in the wild?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, I'm not convinced that the best approach to handling the [ui-automation] tag is to create an iOS-specific variant and retagging everything.  People have been using this tag well for iOS-related matters for over a year now with no confusion.  Perhaps broadening the [ui-automation] tag wiki to include this possible definition is the right approach.  I've asked a question about this on Meta, to see what others feel the best solution is: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105149/should-the-ui-automation-tag-be-broadened-beyond-the-microsoft-specific-definit .

Comment: I respectfully disagree.  The current tag wiki clearly defines the scope.  What would an iOS developer have in common with  .NET developer looking to leverage the automation framework?  These are two divergent topics.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As I point out in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393190/is-there-a-good-tutorial-on-cocoa-touch-automated-ui-testing/5409640#5409640) to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393190/is-there-a-good-tutorial-on-cocoa-touch-automated-ui-testing), I covered UI Automation as part of my recent course on advanced iPhone development.  The video for the "Testing" session that covers this instrument can be found for free [on iTunes U](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=407243028), and the course notes on UI Automation, along with sample scripts, are available [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/Fall2010CourseNotes/ui%20automation.html).

If you have access to the [WWDC 2010 videos](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/), make sure to watch session 306 - "Automating User Interface Testing with Instruments".  That was my first introduction to the topic, and they do a great job of running through the core concepts.

In addition, James Turner's "[How to use UIAutomation to create iPhone UI tests](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1646-how-to-use-uiautomation-to-create-iphone-ui-tests/)" and Alex Vollmer's "[Working with UIAutomation](http://alexvollmer.com/posts/2010/07/03/working-with-uiautomation/)" are both write-ups that I've found useful.

Finally, the [ui-automation](/questions/tagged/ui-automation) tag here on Stack Overflow contains many useful scripts and specific examples of UI Automation in action.